# How to customize a content type css?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes, theming

I have a pdf sharing site with a content type which called PDF. This content type has many fileds (such as author, description, rating, etc). These fields display in simple rows but I want to change either their form and css. for example I want to show Rating number much bigger (and in other color) on the top of each post. what can I do?
*Am I able to define new css classes for these fields?*

Answer (score 2):

create a new template file and add any classes you want. [Here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)'s a good introduction to D7 templates.

your template should be named like this: `node--node_type.tpl.php`. In your case, I think it should be `node--pdf.tpl.php`. You can use `node.tpl.php` as a starting point

Answer (score 2):

One more way is to use a node preprocess hook in your template.php.
It might look something like

```
YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$var){
 if($var['type'] == 'PDF'){
   drupal_add_css(...);
  }
}
```

refer [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) for details